# Ethereum Wallet App transaction failed

Tags: ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am using the Ethereum wallet app made by FreeWallet.net. 
I sent  5 Ether then had a alert failed. What's problem?
Thank!
[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, this app is not related to the official Ethereum Wallet, regardless of the name. It's created by a company called Freewallet.

Comment: seems like the receiver address `()` was left empty?

Comment: Yes, I understand. But when i sent ether, i input address's ether then it is alert failed.